# How may I deactivate the touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

The button under settings unfortunately will be reverted as soon as I reboot. Why is there no button to disable the touchpad permamently?

Comment: What windowmanager are you using ?

Comment: Standard Ubuntu 14.04. Unity?

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating the one yourself? There some workaround.

### StartUp

- Find `StartUp Applications` on dash search and start it up
- Click 'Add' button, this will show you a dialog
- Copy paste the following command to Command textbox :

  ```
  /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled 'false'
  ```
- Add Name and Comment as you like
- Click 'Ok' button

### Shortcut Bind

Or, you can bind the following toggle script with keyboard in the setting

- Go to [System Settings] => [Keyboard] => [Shortcut]
  => [Custom Shortcut] => [+].
- Fill Name as you like
- Fill the command something like the following

  ```
  state=`/usr/bin/gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled`; if [ "$state" == "true" ]; then /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled 'false'; else /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled 'true'; fi
  ```
- Click Ok
- Customize the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the touchpad-indicator applet utility which will place a indicator icon of which you can quickly disable/enable the touchpad with and see if that works and sticks during a reboot. You will need to add this ppa, here are the install details.

Open up Terminal and issue:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

FYI - I don't have this issue and can't reproduce it using a Lenovo Thinkpad with 14.04 Unity (Stock install). So if touchpad-indicator doesn't work either, then you may have something else going on.

Comment: You got a button to permanently disable it under settings? I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 130.

Comment: Yes there is a on/off slider type button switch. I turned it to off and the touchpad is then disabled immediately and for reboots or complete shutdown. You don't have this button?

Comment: I have this button under settings. But it only will work for the current session. On each reboot the touchpad is turned back on.